# Visibility of an Azure Sub hosted in Tenant B when I'm in Tenant A. How is that possible?

Tags: azure

As I understand subscriptions are hosted in their own tenant.

When I'm logged in in tenant A -> Subscriptions, I see a subscription from another tenant (Tenant B).
I can even click it and see the name of the subscription and an information icon saying it is from Tenant B.

I do have access to Tenant B, and even the list of roles of Access Control are different.

- Subscription ID is the same in both tenants.
- Plan is Azure Plan
- I'm a Global Admin in both tenants
- I'm an Owner of the sub in Tenant B
- I'm (plus another colleague who is also able to see the sub when in Tenant A) a Contributor of the sub in Tenant A because of a role assignment to a group where I'm part of. If I remove myself from it, I still see the subscription and if I click on "Subscriptions > "Name of the Sub" > My Permissions" it's all blank.

How is this even possible?

I didn't know you could assign permissions from one tenant to a subscription in another tenant. I didn't set this up so I'm trying to remove it but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-tenant access scenarios in Azure enable resources or subscriptions in one tenant to be accessed by another tenant. This can happen through:

- **B2B (Business-to-Business) guest access**, where users from one tenant can be invited to access resources in another tenant as a guest.
- **Direct assignments of roles across tenants**, for specific scenarios supported by Azure services.

The reason why you can see the subscription from Tenant B while logged into Tenant A is that Azure allows cross-tenant functionalities based on the roles and the connections between the two tenants. This feature helps businesses to work together or manage resources across different organizations in various situations. If you still see the subscription after leaving the Contributor role, it means that there may be leftover permissions or that the visibility is stored in Azure's management portals.

1. **Check Azure AD B2B Settings**: Verify if there are any B2B guest invitations or settings that allow users from Tenant A to access resources in Tenant B.

[image]

[image]

2. **Review Azure RBAC Roles**: Carefully review all the role-based access control (RBAC) assignments for the subscription in both tenants. Ensure that no unexpected groups or users from Tenant A have roles assigned in Tenant B's subscription.

[image]

3. **Use Azure PowerShell or CLI**: Sometimes, using Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI can give you more detailed information about role assignments and permissions than the Azure portal. Use commands to list all role assignments for the subscription in both tenants.

Follow the ***commands*** for **`powershell`**

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SubscriptionId <SubscriptionId>
```

& for **`CLI`**

```
az role assignment list --subscription <SubscriptionId>
```

When you are logged into Tenant A and see a subscription from Tenant B, it indicates that you have complex cross-tenant permissions based on your global admin and ownership roles. To understand and fix the issue, you should review and clean up these permissions and check the B2B guest access settings. If the issue persists you should raise a ticket for support.

***Reference:***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/cross-tenant-access-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/cross-tenant-access-settings-b2b-collaboration

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/multi-tenant-organizations/cross-tenant-synchronization-configure